# About conditional expectation

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Can someone give me some hints on the following problem? Many thanks!!

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be integrable random variables on a probability space $(X,\Sigma, \mathbb{P})$. Show that if both $x$ and $y$ are independent of $z$, then $\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y)=_{\text{a.s.}}\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y,z)$.(Here $\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y,z)$ stands for $\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,\sigma\{y,z\})$, where $\sigma\{y,z\}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $y$ and $z$.)

Comment: *if both x and y are independent of z*... You should really make this more precise: are you assuming that $x$ and $z$ are independent and that $y$ and $z$ are independent?

Answer (score 0):

If the hypothesis is that $x$ and $z$ are independent and that $y$ and $z$ are independent, the result does not hold and the usual counterexample applies: assume that $x$ and $y$ are i.i.d. symmetric Bernoulli $\pm1$ random variables and that $z=xy$.

Then $x$ and $y$ are independent hence $E[x\mid y]=E[x]=0$, while $x=yz$ hence $E[x\mid y,z]=x$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: the conditional expectation is the (almost) **unique** function satisfying...

Comment: Thank you! But your hint is too obscure...

Comment: Do you mean that I should find another form of $\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y,z)$, maybe $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y)\,|\,z]$?

Comment: @QuinnCulver: It might help to add further details to help the OP. Just friendly advice. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Hints start with as little detail as possible. Details can always be added but not taken away.

Comment: @user65018 I mean you should show that $\mathbb{E}(x|y,z)$ satisfies the defining properties of $\mathbb{E}(x|y)$.